# how to add text view to favorite in other activity SQLite DB

Tags: java

i making app quotes in listview with custom view have copy text and share and favorite button all item i want on click button favorite save all item in other activity named favorite

Answer (score 0):

You should find some tutorials on youtube to learn the basics, then come back here later.